# Exotic automorphisms of an extension of Thompson's group $V$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Recall that [R. Thompson's group $V$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) acts transitively on the set $\mathbb{Q}_2$ of dyadic rationals contained in the unit interval $[0,1)$.

> **Main question.** Does there exist a non-trivial $V$-equivariant automorphism $\kappa$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2)$ which fixes every finite set, and satisfies $\kappa(X) \subseteq \overline{X}$ for each $X \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_2$?

Here $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2)$ denotes the group of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ equipped with the symmetric difference $\vartriangle$, with $V$ acting pointwise. We identify $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with the subspace of finitely supported elements of the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is equipped with the Tychonoff topology.

My motivation for asking this question is that such an automorphism $\kappa$ can be extended  to an "exotic" automorphism $\overline{\kappa}$ of the group $ G := \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2) \rtimes V$. I would like to know if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is generated by "elementary" automorphisms, which are built from things such as a fixed subset $Y \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_2$, or certain homeomorphisms of the Cantor space, and have relatively simple formulae. It turns out that the only obstruction to this is the existence of an exotic automorphism of $G$ such as $\overline{\kappa}$.

Some observations can be made: such an automorphism $\kappa$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2)$ must fix every open subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$, and if $O$ and $E$ denote the elements of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with odd and even digit sum respectively, then either $\kappa$ interchanges $O$ and $E$, or fixes them. However, I haven't been able to construct an explicit example.

My supervisor has suggested an approach using Zorn's Lemma, which I will now outline.

A standard dyadic interval (SDI) is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ of the form $\{u \cdot x \ | \ x \in \mathbb{Q}_2\}$, for some (possibly empty) finite word $u$ in $\{0,1\}$, with "$\cdot$" denoting concatenation of words. If $I$ is an SDI, we let $I_o$ and $I_e$ denote the elements of $I$ with odd and even digit sum, respectively.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the subgroup of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q_2})$ generated by sets $I_o$, $I_e$ with $I$ an SDI, and the finite subsets of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. Define $\kappa(I_o) := I_e$ and $\kappa(I_e) := I_o$ for all SDIs $I$, and define $\kappa(X) := X$ for all finite sets $X \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_2$. One can show that $\kappa$ extends to a $V$-equivariant automorphism of $\mathcal{D}$ satisfying the required properties. We want to try to extend $\kappa$ to all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2)$. By an argument using Zorn's Lemma on the set $\mathscr{X}$ of extensions of $\kappa$ which satisfy the required assumptions, one obtains a maximal element $\kappa_m : \mathcal{D}_m \to \mathcal{D}_m$ of $\mathscr{X}$ satisfying the requirements of the main question, for sets in $\mathcal{D}_m$.

> **Question 2.** Can we somehow show that $\mathcal{D}_m = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}_2)$?

Comment: What is the role of the (compact) topology of the power set in the question? if you mean continuous automorphisms, finite subsets form a dense subset of the power set and therefore if you fix them, you act as identity. Since you're introducing this topology, I assume you're using it somewhere.

Comment: @YCor The topology of the power set does not play a role; we allow $\kappa$ to be discontinuous. The topology of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ was introduced solely to specify that $\kappa(X)  \subseteq \overline{X}$ for each $X$ in the power set.